# Нужен сервис для просмотра сайта из разных городов России

Tags: proxy, плагин, webbrowser

Есть сайт, который определяет местоположение пользователя и выдаёт информацию в зависимости от региона. Хотелось бы открыть сайт и увидеть его таким, каким бы его увидел пользователь из Москвы, Питера, Владимира, Ярославля и других городов. Существует ли сервис, предоставляющий соответствующие прокси? В идеале хотелось бы найти плагин для браузера, чтобы в выпадающем списке можно было бы выбирать город и открывать сайт как бы из этого города.